# What does "Choose in someone a person" mean?

Tags: grammaticality

This is a sentence I read from an article posted on WSJ.

> Republicans were choosing in Johnson a person who “can pass their extreme litmus test” on issues such as same sex marriage and abortion.

I am confused with the use of "in" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem strange, but it's a valid if slightly outdated way to identify two things. You could somewhat awkwardly build a phrase with "namely" instead of "in", or you could rephrase it entirely.

You may recognize this example in the popular song from *Toy Story*:

> You've got a friend in me.

This means:

> You've got a friend, namely me.

> I'm a friend for you.

Thus, your example sentence means:

> Republicans were choosing a person who can ..., namely Johnson.

> By choosing Johnson, Republicans were choosing a person who can ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. This makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: Note also that newspapers have a style of packing a lot into each sentence.